# How does `blogdown::serve_site()` setup its local server (Apache/Python/something else)?

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

If I use the R Studio `Addins > Serve Site`, or alternatively `blogdown::serve_site()`, am I setting up an Apache/Python/etc. server on my local machine?  Or is something else happening? How does R Studio and/or blogdown setup this local web server?

I'm trying to recreate this setup without having to use `R Studio > Addins > Serve Site` and just curious as to how things work.

*[EDIT] - I should mention I mainly use Ubuntu and Windows PCs.*

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/tree/master/R

Comment: @Dason You could be more specific: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/master/R/serve.R :)

Comment: @YihuiXie Of course I could. But where would the fun be in that?

Comment: @Dason Haha! Agreed! Absolutely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the preface](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/structure-of-the-book.html) of the **blogdown** book, I recommended that all readers read at least Chapter 1 and Section 3.1 of this book. This question was answered in [Section 1.2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html) of the book:

> LiveReload is implemented via `blogdown::serve_site()`, which is based on the R package [**servr**](https://github.com/yihui/servr).

The **servr** package in turns calls the R package [**httpuv**](https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv) to start a local HTTP server (you could test it with `servr::httd()` to serve any local directory in your browser). It does not use Apache, Python, or other systems. The default server in **blogdown** is not based on `hugo server`, either.

After that sentence in Section 1.2, I inserted a footnote (#7), in which I said if you wish to take advantage of Hugo's built-in server (i.e. `hugo server`), you need to see [Appendix D.2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/livereload.html).

If you have any R Markdown documents in your website project, you cannot simply run `hugo server`. From [Section 2.1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-sites.html) of the **blogdown** book:

> Although we think Hugo is a fantastic static site generator, there is really one and only one major missing feature: the support for R Markdown. That is basically the whole point of the **blogdown** package. This missing feature means that you cannot easily generate results using R code on your web pages, since you can only use static Markdown documents.

Basically `blogdown::serve_site()` does two things: compile R Markdown documents (if there are any), and serve the output pages. The server can be launched in two ways. The default way is through **httpuv**, and the alternative way is `hugo server` if you request **blogdown** to do so via an R option (again, see Appendix D.2). In both ways, R Markdown documents will be automatically recompiled as they are updated.

Note that **blogdown** also (partially) supports [two other static site generators](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/other-generators.html), Jekyll and Hexo. The server launched by `blogdown::serve_site()` has also taken them into consideration. It is not only about Hugo, although I guess the vast majority of **blogdown** users use Hugo.

Answer (score 2):

It runs [hugo](https://gohugo.io/) which is a requirement for `blogdown`, `bookdown` and related projects.  And [hugo](https://gohugo.io/) is its own (embedded) webserver.

This is in fact pretty convenient -- I often just run `hugo server` directly on the command-line. Similarly it also allows you to create sites just via the `hugo` toolchain, or mixed with the R packages, or by switching between them.

And per your edit, here is a script I currently use (on Ubuntu) for a site:

```
#!/bin/bash
hugo server --destination docs --renderToDisk
```

This has the `--destination docs` directory as I am using GitHub's embedded server.

*Edit:* What I describe is correct in itself and a simple alternative, but not the answer to the question which was provided by Yihui. I tend to write more markdown than Rmarkdown so what I described suits me better.

Comment: so to mimic blogdown's `blogdown::serve_site()` command, would I simply type this in my terminal `hugo server --127.0.0.1:XXXX /path/to/index.html --renderToDisk`? replacing *`XXXX`* with some port (which port I don't know)?

Comment: I am inbetween things so can't test but a) I think you just need `hugo server` as it b) then shows in stdout which (standard, fixed) port it uses and c) `--renderToDisk` is only needed if you want to persist (ie to push to GitHub as I do eventually).  I would say just create a quick throwaway site freshly, drop in a them and just play.  Easy enough with `hugo` and the docs are pretty good.

Comment: I'll do that and for future people here's the hugo server manual https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_server/